# Does Intellij IDEA have a hotkey to generate bean mutators/contsructors/toString/etc methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA has a wonderful hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> which popup a dialog to choose a method to generate. However, the most used case is generating several such methods (I usually generate a constructr + default constructor + setters/getters + toString() + hashCode/equals). So a press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> multiple times. Is there a way to do it by pressing just one hotkey?

Comment: As a side note: I recommend to generate constructors / toString / hashCode / equals when you actually _need_ them (ideally with a corresponding test) - and not just because you _might_ need them. It's a lot of code hanging around for no specific purpose, requiring attention when it comes to refactorings and maintenance.

Comment: FYI: As of IntelliJ 2017.2, for macOS, ⌘N is the keyboard shortcut for `Code` > `Generate`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can make them just ONE key. But if you want to try to make your own to do what you want, you can try the official guide to doing it below.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

How this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Macros might help you. Just record one while you generate everything on a random class and bind it to a key.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html